# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn==0.21.0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, version

I tried installing **scikit-learn version 0.21.0** using the command "pip install scikit-learn==0.21.0" in PyCharm. But it is always throwing me the error:

*ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn==0.21.0 (from versions: 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.13.1, 0.14, 0.14
.1, 0.15.0b1, 0.15.0b2, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16b1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17b1, 0.17, 0.17.1, 0.18, 0.18.1, 0.18.2, 0.19b2, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20rc1
, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.20.4, 0.21rc2, 0.21.1, 0.21.2, 0.21.3, 0.22rc2.post1, 0.22rc3, 0.22, 0.22.1, 0.22.2, 0.22.2.post1, 0.23.0rc1, 0.23.0, 0
.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.24.dev0, 0.24.0rc1, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 1.0rc1, 1.0rc2, 1.0, 1.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scikit-learn==0.21.0*

I need to use python 3.8 for my project and have updated the pip and setuptools. I have also checked the path and environment variables minutely.
Can you please help me to figure out if I am missing something?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need a version that is ~1.5 years old?

Comment: I am actually working on a very large old project. Changing the python version will require me to change a hell lot of things in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`scikit-learn` 0.21](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.21.0/#files) requires Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7 but not 3.8. So either you downgrade to Python 3.7 or use a later version of scikit-learn, at least 0.22. Python 3.8 is supported from 0.22 up to the latest 1.0.

Comment: Thank You. At first, I had to uninstall scikit-learn version 1.0.1 and then I tried installing scikit-learn 0.22. It was compatible with the other packages and my problem was solved.